# Update DataGridView every 1 second

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, refresh, fill

I tried to update a DataGridView every 1 second.
I used a timer, but I see the user interface for the form become very slow.
I used a BackgroundWorker, but I didn't get any data in the DataGridView

Here is the DataGridView code:

```
Private Sub OrderBookOffersForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Me.OrderBookOfferBidsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BinanceDataSet.OrderBookOfferBids)
    Me.OrderBookOfferAsksTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BinanceDataSet.OrderBookOfferAsks)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Here is the timer code:

```
Me.OrderBookOfferBidsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BinanceDataSet.OrderBookOfferBids)
Me.OrderBookOfferAsksTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BinanceDataSet.OrderBookOfferAsks)
```

Comment: You can't do anything in the `DoWork` event handler that directly affects the UI.  If you populate a `DataTable` that is bound to a control that you expect to be updated as a result then obviously you are directly affecting the UI, so it's not allowed.

Comment: The original issue is that you are getting all the data every time.  I'm guessing that nothing has changed from one second to the next on most occasions, so what's the point of getting the same data over and over?  The correct option is to have a column in your table for the last update time and then, on each occasion, you can just retrieve data that has a value later than the latest value you already have.  That way, most of your queries will get no data so there's nothing to change, so there's nothing to slow down the UI.  When there is new data, it will only be a small amount.

Comment: thank you for your replay,i tried to load financial book order ,its data changed with lower than asecond second,i updated allready in my database from another form,but i need this form to update date live

Comment: `updated allready in my database from another form` Another form or another app?  The great advise you were given still applies

Comment: thank you for your replay,now i update the database from another form ,but the final work it will be from another computer or service,i can make a temporary soluthion if it from another page,but i need the solution as i have only database with recently updated .

Comment: Now there are "pages"??? At any rate you already have one great answer - pick up new rows based on a Date/Timestamp column.  Another way is with a DataAdapter which will automatically pick up new and changed rows.

Comment: not page ,this by mistake ,i mean form

Comment: if i use this code (Me.OrderBookOfferBidsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BinanceDataSet.OrderBookOfferBids)
)  any time it get updated row from database and automatically datagridview updated also,but the problem this code not working inside BackgroundWorker1,and if used timer the form user interface become slowly

Comment: I've already told you why it won't work in the `DoWork` event handler of a `BackgroundWorker` and I've also already told you how to address the issue that caused you to think that you needed a `BackgroundWorker` in the first place. How about you try to actually do what has been suggested?

Comment: thank you for your replay,i understand what explain allready but the data in database is changing in lower than a second ,so if i check if database changed is useless because i know it allready must be changed more times in 1 second from outside project or coputer connected to database,but i try to update the my project datagridview every 1 second ,i didnot need my form to become not responding ,how i can get the data from database live less than 1 second and update the datagridview without my form become not responding.